# How do i extrude "screws" from my model

Tags: modeling, extrude

I'm making a simple gun model made of mostly cubes but the reference image contains a lot of "screw" extrusions that makes my model look incomplete. Is it possible to do it without individually modelling the screws and placing? If so, how? I cant provide image of my model but imagine it as the reference without the screws.
[image: ingram mac 10]

Comment: If you can provide images of your reference, and your model that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to make a round peg fit a square hole in Blender, that's generally more difficult than it's worth.

If you search "Cutting round holes Blender," there are some good resources out there for how to make a round element match up with a square element.

However, it's usually much more convenient to just model the greeble separately. Unless you have some specific reason that it has to be attached, I'd highly recommend this method. Keep in mind that you don't need to model a whole screw. You don't even have to model the whole head of the screw. You only need to model the part that will be seen, which is a tiny sliver of a disk with a slit in it.

If you're wanting to model any part of the hole or dent that the screw goes into on the weapon, it might be enough to just subdivide that area and "push" it in a little. If you want something more than that, a Boolean modifier would be a great way to cut out the part of the hole that you're interested in seeing.

I'll try to upload some images later today, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I think i get what you mean. I just thought if there was any way then i could extrude it inwards as well which would be useful too.

Comment: I'll add some to my answer...

Answer (score 0):

If the final model is going to be used in a game it depends on how many polygons your final model should have. For modern game engines I'd go for a little more than just some cubes. For Unity, UE4 and even Leadwerks I'd go for at least 500.

While you should definitely take a look at the looptools addon for modeling in general, I'd go with Matt's approach and model the screws from separate meshes. It's easier and it definitely saves polygons in areas where they won't be necessary.

Comment: Might I ask why such a high polygon amount for modern game engines? Excuse me for my questions this only my  second project on blender :).